# Areas under the cumulative distribution function

Tags: solution-verification, alternative-proof, cumulative-distribution-functions

I need to show that one distribution, $\Phi_1$, $\textbf{second-order}$ stochastically dominates the other, $\Phi_2$. These are discrete distributions. The distributions are:

$\Phi_1(x)$=
$\begin{cases}
    0.25,& \text{if } 0 \leq x<10\\
    0.6,& \text{if } 10 \leq x<20 \\
    0.85 & \text{if } 20 \leq x<40 \\
    0.95 & \text{if } 40 \leq x<100 \\
1       & \text{if } x \geq 100
\end{cases}$

and,

$\Phi_2(x)$=
$\begin{cases}
    0.28, & \text{if } 0 \leq x<10\\
    0.8, & \text{if } 10 \leq x<35 \\
    0.86 & \text{if } 35 \leq x<100 \\
    1 & \text{if } x \geq 100 \\       
\end{cases}$

I am looking for SOSD relationships precisely. The way I'm going about this is as follows. I'm showing that $\int^{x}_{-\infty} \Phi_1 (x) dx \leq \int^{x}_{-\infty} \Phi_2 (x) dx$ for all $x$: 
$\int^{10}_{0} 0.25 dx = 2.5 \leq \int^{10}_{0} 0.28 dx = 2.8$ 
$\int^{20}_{10} 0.6 dx = 6 \leq \int^{20}_{10}0.8 dx = 8 $ 

However, from now on:

$\int^{35}_{20} 0.85 dx = 12.75 \geq \int^{35}_{20} 0.8 dx = 12$ 
$\int^{35}_{40} 0.85 dx \leq \int^{35}_{40} 0.86 dx $ 
$\int^{40}_{100} 0.95 dx \geq \int^{40}_{100} 0.86 dx$

What I am getting wrong? $\int^{x}_{-\infty} \Phi_1 (x) dx \leq \int^{x}_{-\infty} \Phi_2 (x) dx$ for some $x$, but not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{10}\Phi_1(x)dx=2.5<\int_{-\infty}^{10}\Phi_2(x)dx=2.8$$

and the integral can never be larger for the first cdf because .25 is less than .28. Then for 10 to 20 we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{20}\Phi_1(x)dx=2.5+6=8.5<\int_{-\infty}^{20}\Phi_2(x)dx=2.8+8=10.8$$

and it could not have been greater because .6 < .8. Then for 20 to 35 we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{35}\Phi_1(x)dx=8.5+12.75=21.25<\int_{-\infty}^{35}\Phi_2(x)dx=10.8+12=22.8$$

For 35 to 40 we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{40}\Phi_1(x)dx=21.25+4.25=25.5<\int_{-\infty}^{40}\Phi_2(x)dx=22.8+4.3=27.1$$

And lastly

$$\int_{-\infty}^{100}\Phi_1(x)dx=25.5+57=82.5<\int_{-\infty}^{100}\Phi_1(x)dx=27.1+55.9=83$$

Comment: The stochastic dominance you mention is first-order dominance. How about second-order? This would be for the area under the CDF, which is the integral of the CDF.

Comment: I see, interesting. A potential error comes from not going from negative infinity to the current value. For instance for $\int_{-\infty}^{35}\Phi(x)dx$, we have $2.5+6+12.75<2.8+8+12$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Stacker. Do we assume that when calculating the improper integral:

$\int^{10}_{-\infty} \Phi_1 (x) dx = \lim_{t \to -\infty} \int^{10}_{t} 1/4 dx = 1/4 * 10 = 2.5 $, because technically the limit would tend to $+ \infty$.

Comment: The implicit part of your cdfs are that $\Phi(x)=0,x<0$. So the integral you mentioned is indeed 2.5 (integral from -infty to 0 plus integral from 0 to 10 is 0 + 2.5)

Comment: Ah, true, I see it now clearly. What if I have got the following:
$\Phi_0 (x) = 0.5$ for $-100 \leq x < 250$; $\Phi_0(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 250$. Would the area not be computed ?

Comment: Then for x<-100 the integral is 0, for x between -100 and 250 it is (x+100)(.5), and for x>250 it is 175+(x-250). So as x goes to positive infinity it does go to infinity. But for our problem since the $\Phi_2(x)$ ended higher than Phi1 then it will always be higher than Phi1 as you go to infinity.